# how to check the string is Null or not in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, shell-script

I had a script like this

```
    #!/bin/bash
    line="hello"

    if [ -z $line ] ; then
            echo "String null"
    fi
```

This will work properly, but when I give the `line`as follows

```
    line="hello welcome"
```

It will through the error as

```
     a.sh: 5: [: hello: unexpected operator
```

In that situation , how can I check that is Null or not ??

Comment: Quote your vars in `[`: see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031 or, as the guide says, use `[[`...

Comment: I always use `if [ x = "x$foo" ] ; then echo null ; else echo not null ; fi` a bit dirt, but have been working since 1986.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the if condition give the $line in the double quotes it will work fine

```
#!/bin/bash
line="hello welcome "

if [ -z "$line" ] ; then
        echo "String null"
fi
```